# Search value in array and if not found added

Tags: php, arrays, search

I have an array with the following format:

```
$array = Array(
  Array('id' => 77, 'title' => 'title'),
  Array('id' => 43, 'title' => 'title2'),
  Array('id' => null, 'title' => 'title3'),
  Array('id' => null, 'title' => null),
);
```

This array is populated dynamically, this is just an example. Also, i have a second array with the format:

```
$searchingArray = Array('43', '5');
```

The main idea is to search if values from `$searchingArray` are in `$array` and if not exists then added. My function is:

```
function addId($id, $ignoreIfFound=false) {
  foreach ($array as $values) {
     if ($values['id'] and $values['id'] == $id) {
       if (!$ignoreIfFound) {
         $array[] = Array('id' => $id, 'title' => 'test5');
         break;
       }
       else{
       // do nothing
      }
    }else{
       $array[] = Array('id' => $id, 'title' => 'test5');
       break;
    }
  }
}

foreach ($searchingArray as $id) {
    $this->addId($id, true);
}
```

For given example the result should be:

```
$array = Array(
     Array('id' => 77, 'title' => 'title'),
     Array('id' => 43, 'title' => 'title2'),
     Array('id' => null, 'title' => 'title3'),
     Array('id' => null, 'title' => null),
     Array('id' => 5, 'title' => 'test5'),
  );
```

Can you tell me what it is wrong with my code?

Comment: "Can you tell me what it is wrong with my code?" - You should be able to tell us that, what errors are you getting / what isn't working? (Include any error in your question)

Comment: In your function you have the variable `$array` which is not in the scope of that function. You should add a new parameters and pass the array.

Comment: For given example the value Array('id' => 43, title => 'title5') appear 2 times which is wrong.

Comment: @Daan $array is a private elements but i didn't write the hole class (it was unecessary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

First extract the `id` column out of your array with [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php). After this simply loop through your search array and check with [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) if they id already exists or not. If not simply add it to the array.

```
$ids = array_column($array, "id");

foreach($searchingArray as $search) {
    if(!in_array($search, $ids)) {
        $array[] = ["id" => $search, "title" => "title" . $search];
    }
}
```

Comment: this is what i've answered also +1, just push another set if not found on any gathered ids

Comment: Thank you, but i cannot use array_column because i am using php 5.3

Comment: @OSOMAN Then simply replace the line with this one: `$ids = array_map(function($v){return $v["id"];}, $array);`